# Grails. domain class and its methods?

Tags: grails

For example, I read in book that if we created relationship 1:m, Grails automatically add methods `addTo*` and `removeTo*`

and now i think, how i can see all methods my domain class?

for example, some like this: `Domain.getAllMethods()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) on the left pane under Domain.

While Domain.metaClass.methods will give you the list, you're going to need actual documentation behind how they work.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily via the [metaclass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Evaluating+the+MetaClass+runtime):

```
println Domain.metaClass.methods
```